# Atom JSHint for JavaScript inside HTML

Tags: configuration, npm, jshint, atom-editor

I just started using [Atom](https://atom.io/). I installed `linter-jshint` and `jshint`

After setting the `jshint` executable path. I had `jshint` working on JavaScript files. However, after several hours I still cannot get it to work with JavaScript in HTML files. I looked in `package.json` and the docs but did not find something that works.

I saw that there is a flag `--extract=[auto|always|never]`. But I am not sure how to use it in Atom.

Answer (score 2):

[`linter-jshint`](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint) package has a `lintInlineJavaScript` configuration that you can enable to make it lint html files.

You can find more about its configuration in its [GitHub README](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint#settings).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested add the **lintInlineJavaScript** jshint setting to Atom *config.cson*

`"linter-jshint":
    executablePath: "~/.atom/packages/atom-jshint"
    lintInlineJavaScript: true
    disableWhenNoJshintrcFileInPath: false`

(^ so it now should now lint `<script>` inside *.html file but something is wrong as I can only get it to work with *.js files)

Comment: did you get it working on html files? I scouted all forums I could, applied all I read, but can't make it run on html files. JS files are ok though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get inline linting to work by adding the following to the scopes (in the settings window inside Atom for Linter Jshint): source.js.embedded.html.

You also need to have the option "Lint Inline Java Script" switched on.